# Question about exact meaning of "a premium paid" in the given context.

Tags: phrase-meaning

A Text:
Amazon parrots are native to the New World. Indeed, Christopher Columbus himself apparently gave the name “Amazon” to the green. Short winged parrots that he brought back to Europe after his first voyage here. There are 27 species of Amazon parrots. Most parrot species are bred successfully in captivity and several types of Amazons are available from breeders and pet stores here in Canada. Prices generally range, depending on the species, from $800 to $1600, with a **premium paid** for the breeds that are considered to be better “talkers”

1. What does "with a premium paid for" mean in the last sentence?
2. Who pays?
3. Whom does "he" (that somebody in the 2nd question) pay to?
4. And what exactly does "that somebody" pay?

Comment: It's talking about prices, so the payor is the purchaser; he pays it, obviously, to a seller--a breeder or pet store. A 'premium' in this context is an extra amount: better talkers command a higher price.

Comment: thanks a lot, I thought so, but dictionary translates it into our language as  "insurance payment"

Comment: @JaneMiller: that's a different meaning of _premium_. In the context of insurance, it would be understood in that sense.

Comment: You should check all the definitions in an English dictionary. Translations have to guess which definition fits best, but often pick the wrong one.